# Como fazer uma DIV desaparecer após alguns segundos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Na minha aventura a descobrir html/php, deparei-me com outro problema.
Eu tenho uma DIV, onde aparece os dados do utilizador após um login correto, e gostaria de fazer essa DIV desaparecer através de javascript.

Este é o meu index.php:

```
<?php include('server.php');

    //se não estiver logado, não consegue aceder a esta página
    if (empty($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location: login.php');
    }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mobies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#goaway").fadeOut().empty();
        }, 5000);
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="goaway">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Página Principal</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])): ?>
            <div class="error success">
                <h3>
                    <?php
                        echo $_SESSION['success'];
                        unset($_SESSION['success']);
                    ?>
                </h3>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"])): ?>
            <p>Bem-vindo <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
            <p><a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">Logout</a></p>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

No meu código tenho esta função:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#goaway").fadeOut().empty();
        }, 5000);
</script>
```

Pelas minhas pesquisas, vários tutoriais usam esta função para fazer a DIV desaparecer, mas eu não estou conseguindo.

Estou fazendo algo de errado? Ou esqueci de algo importante?

Quando faço um `alert("Olá Mundo!")` no script, ele funciona assim que se faz o login.

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código estava faltando a inclusão do jQuery. Seu código correto ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php include('server.php');

    //se não estiver logado, não consegue aceder a esta página
    if (empty($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location: login.php');
    }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mobies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="goaway">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Página Principal</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])): ?>
            <div class="error success">
                <h3>
                    <?php
                        echo $_SESSION['success'];
                        unset($_SESSION['success']);
                    ?>
                </h3>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"])): ?>
            <p>Bem-vindo <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
            <p><a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">Logout</a></p>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <!-- jQUery-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ação para ocultar a div depois de 5 segundos -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#goaway").fadeOut().empty();
            }, 5000);
        }, false);
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Com o script abaixo você conseguiria fazer isso. O número '2000' na função é a quantidade desejada de segundos multiplicada por mil, ou seja, se você deseja ocultar a `div` em 6 segundos = 6000, se em 4 = 4000 e assim sucessivamente.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#teste').fadeOut('fast');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste">
<p>teste</p>
</div>
```